# How can I create a DLL for extension methods in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, dll, visual-studio-extensions

Ladies and gentlemen, 
I am trying to create a DLL I can share between a few different projects that includes a variety of extension methods I've written to simplify my code. In understand such DLL's are feasable to share between C# and VB.net projects. I however have been unable thus far to create a DLL, or even to include the sub project and reference it that way and be able to access my extensions.

I am able to see the reference in the object browser, but import statements do not bring up my sub-project reference as an option. VB.net does not allow me to place the extensions within classes, and I can't seem to find any clues on the web that would explain this. Thanks in advance.

Example...

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Extensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function ToEnum(Of T)(ByVal value As String) As T
        Try
            Return (CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(T), value.Replace(" ", ""), True), T))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return (CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(T), 0, True), T))
        End Try

    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Looks like you are using VS2010.  Do strongly favor Enum.TryParse().  And keep in mind what localization will do to this code.

Comment: Thanks Hans, the try/catch is probably less efficient I imagine? Plus the type conversion delay? I deal with a lot of enum conversions in my code so every little bit helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to mark your Extensions module with the Public keyword. Also, make sure that your project properties in your consuming project lists your library project as a reference; simply appearing in the Object Browser doesn't mean you've set up the reference properly.

Comment: Wow... feeling a bit silly for not catching that. Thanks Jason!

Answer (score 0):

The following console application code is perhaps nonsensical, but leverages your exact code above with the exception that I made your module `Public` versus the default of `Friend`.

In my solution, `ClassLibrary3` is the VB class library project and included as a reference in the console application project.

```
Imports ClassLibrary3.Extensions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim f As String = "hello"

        Console.WriteLine(f.ToEnum(Of System.ConsoleColor)())
    End Sub

End Module
```